# JvisualVM --> Profiling --> Garbage Collection

Tags: garbage-collection, jvisualvm

On clicking  garbage collection tab in profiling, it will really do garbage collection or its optional? I know when we call system.gc() it not assured it will call garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

As per SCJP6 Chapter 3: Assignments

> **When Does the Garbage Collector Run?**
>
> The garbage collector is under the control of the JVM. The JVM decides
>   when to run the garbage collector. From within your Java program you
>   can ask the JVM to run the garbage collector, *but there are no
>   guarantees*, under any circumstances, that the JVM will comply. Left to
>   its own devices, the JVM will typically run the garbage collector when
>   it senses that memory is running low. Experience indicates that when
>   your Java program makes a request for garbage collection, the JVM will
>   usually grant your request in short order, but there are no
>   guarantees. Just when you think you can count on it, the JVM will
>   decide to ignore your request.